# Why wasn't std::forward_list given a count() member function?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, containers, forward-list

I understand why `std::forward_list` [**does not have a `size()` member function**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2543.htm), since an `O(1)` version would mess up the complexity of certain `splice()` overloads, and since an `O(N)` version would be inconsistent with all the rest of the Standard Library's containers.

It is also true that both `std::list` and `std::forward_list` already have several other member functions with the same semantics as their cousins from the `<algorithm>` corner of the Standard Library (`merge()`, `reverse()`, `remove()`, `remove_if()`, `unique()`, `sort()`).

So why wasn't a `count()`  member function of `O(N)` complexity provided to `std::forward_list` that had the semantics of returning `std::distance(std::begin(some_list), std::end(some_list))`?

Comment: Basically, the STL classes are already big enough and adding such member functions on one of them would trigger something in the users that would want it in all the other STL containers. And, as you said (and it is already mentioned in the proposal), `std::distance` can get the size for you in no more time, so there is little harm.

Comment: @Morwenn but there would be no need to have `count()` in any other container since they all already have `size()`.

Comment: @rhalbersma: And there's no need to have `count()` in any container, since we already have `std::distance()`.

Comment: @rhalbersma I think that many users would still ask "Why is there a `count` function in `std::forward_list` while it is not present in the other containers?", even though they already have `size`.

Comment: @rhalbersma as a rule of thumb, containers have the member functions that they can *efficiently* support, or where the implementation differs from generic implementations. `std::map` has a `find` member function because the semantics of `std::find` are not appropriate, and `vector` has an `operator[]` because it can be implemented to run in constant time. A `std::count` function satisfies neither of those: it is not a promise that "this operation can be done efficiently", and its semantics don't differ from the non-member `std::distance`. So why would it be added? What beenfit does it have?

Comment: @jalf good point, I guess I just find `std::distance` just too verbose to write

Comment: @rhalbersma Wait for ranges an verbose will somehow be reduced.

Comment: @Morwenn: That's gonna be a long wait though :( No ranges in C++14

Comment: @AndyProwl Yeah, I know, and they still do not seem to agree on half of points :/

Comment: @rhalbersma write a free function `size_t count(const std::forward_list<T>&);` and use that? :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The member functions you mention (`merge()`, `reverse()`, `remove()`, `remove_if()`, `unique()`, `sort()`) are provided because they have better complexity than the generic algorithms in the `<algorithm>` standard headers.

A member function such as `count()`, on the other hand, would not have better complexity than `std::distance(std::begin(some_list), std::end(some_list))`.

Also, it may be misinterpreted as the better-complexity version of the [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) generic algorithm, which does something basically different.

Comment: true, it would be a convenience function, much like `std::begin()`/`std::end()` for `std::array`

Comment: @rhalbersma: `std::begin()` and `std::end()` are more than just a convenience; they provide a generic way to get the bounds of any iterable container, including arrays.

Comment: `std::count(begin(list), end(list), [](auto&&){ return true; });` :D

Comment: @Xeo `std::count_if` , you mean

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that because, unlike the functions you listed, using the standard library algorithm for a count or size function would be just as fast a version that had direct access to the underlying implementation.

Each of the member functions you mentioned for `std::forward_list` are actually faster when implemented as members.  In particular, they can operate without performing any unnecessary copies or moves of the contained data.  The standard library algorithm versions require the data in the container to be copied or moved.